# Why spark sql is preferred over hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I am evaluating both spark sql and  hive with processing engine as spark .Most people prefer to use spark sql over hive with spark . I feel hive with spark is same as spark sql . Or I am missing anything here. Is there any advantages of using spark sql over hive which run on spark processing engine.

Any clue would be helpful

Comment: one obvious advantage of Spark is that it's not limited to SQL api (RDD and DataFrame)

Answer (score 0):

One point would be the difference in how the queries are executed.

While Hive with Spark execution engine, for each query you spin up a new set of executors, on Spark SQL you have a Spark session with a set of long-living executors where you can cache data (create temporary tables) which can speed up your queries substantially.